# JavaFX set listview item bgcolor programmatically

Tags: java, listview, javafx

I am trying to change color of selected item in listView programmatically.
By using listView.setCellFactory(...) I have changed color of all items, but I need only one. Anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a listener to [the `selected` property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Cell.html) and change the background on a change, however it would be much easier to do this using a CSS stylesheet containing the following rule (assuming you've assigned the `list-view-id` `id` to the `ListView`):

```css
#list-view-id .list-cell:selected {
    -fx-background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: The thing is that I need to left selected item in some different color for every new selected item. Imagine that you have list, and you need to change color for last 3 item was selected.